# How to delete file(s) from source s3 bucket after lambda successfully copies file(s) to destination s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following the lambda function which uses an s3 trigger to copy files from a source to a destination bucket. This is working fine.

```
import os
import logging
import boto3

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

DST_BUCKET = os.environ.get('DST_BUCKET')
REGION = os.environ.get('REGION')

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=REGION)

def handler(event, context):
   LOGGER.info('Event structure: %s', event)
   LOGGER.info('DST_BUCKET: %s', DST_BUCKET)

   for record in event['Records']:
       src_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
       src_key = record['s3']['object']['key']

       copy_source = {
           'Bucket': src_bucket,
           'Key': src_key
       }
       LOGGER.info('copy_source: %s', copy_source)
       bucket = s3.Bucket(DST_BUCKET)
       bucket.copy(copy_source, src_key)

   return {
       'status': 'ok'
   }
```

What I'm wanting to do now is to modify the code above to delete the file(s) (not the folder) from the source bucket *after* successful upload to the destination bucket.

Use case: user uploads three files, two legit csv file and one corrupted csv file. Lambda triggers on source bucket, begins the copying of those files. Lambda loops through the files outputting successful or true when done and false if there were issues along with the filename, then deletes those successfully uploaded from the *source* bucket.

I've tried various try/catch blocks for this but it ends up either deleting the entire folder or there's issues synchronizing the buckets where the file is deleted from the source folder before successful upload, etc.

I dont want to do away with the loop above so that if multiple files are uploaded it will loop through all of them and similarly delete all of them when successfully uploaded to the other bucket. Unsure if a simple boolean would be sufficient for this use case or another flag of some sort. The flag would have to keep track of the specific key, though, so that it knows which was successful and not.

Comment: Why, exactly, would calling `s3.Object(src_bucket, src_key).delete()` after the copy call not do what you want?

Comment: AWS don't have concept of retaining folder name, its only Bucket and Objects you deal with . 
also you can use s3 event triggers to run lambdas everytimea. file is added to the bucket rather than looping .

Comment: @AnonCoward that would likely work, I just wanted to make sure the delete happens only after the successful copying to the destination folder, not before. Seems like there would need to be more error handling for something like that (i.e., try/catch etc).

Comment: @ArjunDandagi I am using event triggers. The lambda triggers when files are added (I stated this above..) to the source bucket. The problem is how to delete the file after successful copying of the file(s) from the source to the destination bucket folder and only after successful copying of the file(s). The loop is best practice for this use case which is why im keeping that, thanks.

Comment: Well, without error handling, the code will just fail now, so it'll do the right thing, with the possible exception of what'd happen if AWS ever added more than one event to S3 Triggers.  Given how much code must exist that assumes there will only ever be one event, that seems unlikely to happen anytime soon, but you never know, I suppose.

Comment: Right there are limitations with using s3 triggers across the board right now for all use cases which is why Im using the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before removing the file from the source bucket, you can verify that it was uploaded correctly using `s3.Object(DST_BUCKET, src_key).load()`:

```
import os
import logging
import boto3

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

DST_BUCKET = os.environ.get('DST_BUCKET')
REGION = os.environ.get('REGION')

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=REGION)

def handler(event, context):
    LOGGER.info(f'Event structure: {event}')
    LOGGER.info(f'DST_BUCKET: {DST_BUCKET}')

    for record in event['Records']:
        src_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        src_key = record['s3']['object']['key']

        copy_source = {
                    'Bucket': src_bucket,
                    'Key': src_key
                        }
        LOGGER.info(f'copy_source: {copy_source}')
        bucket = s3.Bucket(DST_BUCKET)
        bucket.copy(copy_source, src_key)

        try:
            #Check file
            s3.Object(DST_BUCKET, src_key).load()
            LOGGER.info(f"File {src_key} uploaded to Bucket {DST_BUCKET}")
            # Delete the file from the source bucket
            s3.Object(src_bucket, src_key).delete()
            LOGGER.info(f"File {src_key} deleted from Bucket {src_bucket}")
    
        except Exception as e:
            return {"error":str(e)}

    return {'status': 'ok'}
```

I've tested it with files in two different regions and worked great for me.